# How can I add command line arguments in VS Code for C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I want to know where to put command line arguments in VS Code for C. I know in Visual studio you can hit the project and add the command line arguments, but I do not know how to do that in VS Code.

Comment: By which method do you execute the program? – Debugging using F5 key, or an extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{
     "name": "C Launch",
     "request": "launch",
     "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
     "args": ["arg1", "arg2"],
     "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

put the above line in the `.vscode/launch.json` file in your working directory. Be sure to replace `a.out` with your name of program.
For further details check [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference).